# Automating Swing application

Tags: java, swing, rcp

I've an existing RCP application running on windows platform. I want to design an application in java to open the application, fill the from and click the buttons. Is it possible?

Comment: It would be easier to modify the RCP application to accept form input from an outside source.

Comment: They have converted it as executable. I don't have source.

Comment: Take a look at the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class.  Good luck.

Comment: This question is not very specific.  Yes it is possible, but not advisable.  In any case I am voting to close the question as being primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Gilbert Is there are possiblity to find a specific message box has appeared or not??

Comment: Sure. You use Robot to snap an image of the RCP application, and process the image pixel by pixel.  Frankly, it would be easier to write another Java application that duplicates the functionality of the RCP application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an [RCP](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Rich_Client_Platform) (Rich Client Platform) application then it should be using SWT (not Swing) and you can do automation tasks using [SWTBot](http://eclipse.org/swtbot/).